# Using LEFT function with LEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Left(GIFTHEADER.pID + GIFTHEADER.PID + '-' + Cast(PAYMENTDETAIL.PLINENO as Varchar),18)
AS TRANSACTIONREF...
```

Currently my value looks like this:

```
ABC0005953ABC0005953
```

I want to simply strip off the first 4 characters from GIFTHEADER.pID

Comment: Yes, but i need to delete that old question.

Comment: why? you asked about 4 there in comments and you got answers